# How can I validate that date is in format DD.YY.MMMM in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, validation, date

I would like to have a program that asks a valid date like 05.04.2018 or 5.4.2018 (fifth of April 2018). I tried to write a first version that checks if the date is format 05.04.2018. Why do this approach returns AttributeError
and how to fix it?

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
#!/usr/bin/python
from datetime import datetime

def validate_date():
    try:
        date = input("Give the date of the form DD.MM.YYYY: ")
        valid_date = date.strptime(date, '%d.%m.%Y')
    except ValueError:
        raise ValueError("The date must be of the form DD.MM.YYYY")
    except SyntaxError:
        raise SyntaxError("Wrong syntax")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    alkuaika = validate_date()
```

The output was

```
Give the date of the form DD.MM.YYYY: 12.12.20128
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "koe.py", line 15, in <module>
    alkuaika = validate_date()
  File "koe.py", line 8, in validate_date
    valid_date = date.strptime(date, '%d.%m.%Y')
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'strptime'
```

Comment: `datetime.strptime` not `date.strptime`: typo

Comment: pretty much that... you're trying to look for a string method strptime which doesn't exist...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you use a input() function,you must send the data in quotes, "05.09.1990" will work but 05.09.1990 won't work which will throw "unexpected EOF while parsing" error, and by the even if you send through quotes , a string datatype doesn't have strptime method.